# Replace multiple strings in a list with a string in python and get the count of replaced string occurence

Tags: python, selenium, redundancy

I need to replace all the strings in Current_List.. that are in AllLimit list with string 'Limits'
and replace all the strings that are in AllTech list with sring 'Tech'  and
count the occurence of 'Limits' and 'Tech'.
Im using the below code, which is serving the above purpose. In anyway, can I reduce redundancy in the code.

```
AllTech = ['Power Lost', 'Failure', 'no Supply']
AllLimit = ['High Temp', 'Low Humid']
current_list = ['High Temp', 'Low Humid', 'Power Lost', 'no Supply' ]

fc =  [sub.replace('High Temp', 'Limits')
           .replace('Low Humid', 'Limits')
           .replace('Power Lost', 'Tech')
           .replace('no Supply', 'Tech') for sub in current_list]

print (fc.count("Tech"))
print (fc.count("Limits"))
```

Comment: you might need a huge loop for current list that encompasses alltech and all limit and they might have two loops each themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
all_tech = ['Power Lost', 'Failure', 'no Supply']
all_limit = ['High Temp', 'Low Humid']
current_list = ['High Temp', 'Low Humid', 'Power Lost', 'no Supply']


for item in current_list:
    if item in all_limit:
        current_list.remove('High Temp')
        current_list.remove('Low Humid')
        current_list.insert(0, 'Limit')
        current_list.insert(1, 'Limit')
    if item in all_tech:
        current_list.remove('Power Lost')
        current_list.remove('no Supply')
        current_list.insert(0, 'Tech')
        current_list.insert(2, 'Tech')
print(current_list)
print(current_list.count('Tech'))
print(current_list.count('Limit'))
```

I hope this helps, let me know if this is or isn't what you are looking for.

Comment: The code I've mentioned worked for me, I wanted to know, if there is a way to make my code less redundant. Like, without mentioning each and every string of Current_list, can I  replace them at a time.

Comment: I don't think there is, you would have to atleast mention what you want to change it to and maybe the index of the list